# finding the error pattern from the syndrome

Tags: coding-theory

If the parity check matrix is 
 $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        \end{matrix}
$$
As it has two identical columns how do we decide the error pattern when we get   **001** as the syndrome
Is it  **01000** or **00010** ?

Comment: We can't.  To correct one error, the minimum distance has to be $3$.  But in a code whose parity check matrix has identical columns, there are codewords of weight $2$, and the minimum distance is therefore at most $2$.  In this particular code, $01001$ is a codeword of weight $2$.

Comment: @WillOrrick that comment should be an answer, I think

Comment: @leonbloy: I've added it as an answer (expanded slightly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't. To correct one error, the minimum distance has to be $3$. But in a code whose parity check matrix has identical columns, there are codewords of weight $2$, and the minimum distance is therefore at most $2$.

In general, if the parity check matrix of a binary linear code has two identical columns, then the word with $1$s in the positions of the identical columns and $0$s elsewhere is a codeword of weight $2$.  In this particular code, $01001$ is such a codeword.  But $00000$ is also a codeword, as it is of any linear code.  Therefore if the $1$ in the second position of $01001$ is changed to a $0$, the resulting word, $00001$ will be equidistant from the codewords $01001$ and $00000$.  One cannot then say what the correct decoding should be.